# Architecture to store layout data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm not looking for someone to write all the code, I'm looking mainly for more theoretical information.

I'd like to develop and interface that uses drag and drop and cakephp as a backend.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to store the data, since it's not grouped like name, address etc.

How should I go about building this?  Just create "pods" with ids that can be stored?  What happens if my data pods are various sizes etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Uuuuhm... I'm not sure I'm following, but when working with PHP, I know two ways to store data: MySQL and text files, both with their shortcomings and advantages. Is this just what you were looking for? Because honestly, if not, I think you should explain a bit more, and perhaps give examples.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a design question?  Since you posted vague details, my answer can only be very vague --  try thinking about things like your requirements and limitations are.  Is there common parts to your data, such that you can make assumptions to simplify it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood that correctly, but i'm assuming that you mean dynamic data type ? I'm to define your data struct on the fly.
If yes you can go two attemps: 
- more complicated, yet more efficient and powerfull would be an EAV  concept, same it used in Magento if you are familiar with it, if not it bascially gives you power to define your object structure using predefined data types -> wiki:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model
- Simple approach, less efficient and powerful, but blast easy to implement is Expandable behavior for cakePHP model